# Radial vs tangential component of electrical field due to dipole

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole

I was wondering that why should the maximum magnitude (with respect to $\theta$) of radial component of electrical field of an electric dipole, $$E_r=-\partial V/\partial r=\frac{2p \cos\theta}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}$$ be $\textbf{twice}$ the maximum magnitude of tangential component, $$E_\theta=-\partial V/r\partial \theta=\frac{p \sin\theta}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^3}$$ physically? [reference Griffiths: Introduction to electrodynamics 4th Ed., section 4.4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the max of $E_r$ that is twice the max of $E_\theta$.  For each individual charge, the magnitude of $E_r$ is much larger than that of $E_\theta$ because the electric field is directed from the charge toward or away from the observation point.  The tangential component comes from the angular separation of the charges at the observation point which is small.

At $\theta = 0$ where the radial component is the largest is also where the charges have the largest separation and the smallest cancelling of radial component. $E_\theta$ is largest at $\theta = \pi/2$ where the $\theta$ components add, but with the small separation between charges, the tangential components are very small.

This is the arm waving explanation, but you should look at your reference text to see exactly how those values were calculated and where the factor of 2 comes from.